# Concurrency issue or something else? .save() method + DB timing

Tags: django, database, django-models, concurrency

So the situtation is this:
I have an endpoint `A` that creates data and calls .save() on that data (call this `functionA`) which also sends a post request to an external 3rd party API that will call my endpoint `B` (call this `functionB`)

```
def functionA():
    try:
        with transaction.atomic()
            newData = Blog(title="new blog")
            newData.save()

            # findSavedBlog = Blog.objects.get(title="new blog")
            # print(findSavedBlog) 

            r = requests.post('www.thirdpartyapi.com/confirm_blog_creation/', some_data) # this post request will trigger the third party to send a post request to endpoint calling functionB
            return HttpResponse("Result was: " + r.status)
```

```
def functionB():
    blogTitle = request.POST.get('blog_title') # assume this evaluates to 'new blog'
    # sleep(20)
    try:
        findBlog = Blog.objects.get(title=blogTitle) # again this will be the same as Blog.objects.get(title="new blog")

    except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
        print("Blog not found!")
```

If I uncomment the `findSavedBlog` portion of functionA, it will print the saved blog, but functionB will still fail.

If I add in a `sleep` to function B to wait for the DB to finish writing and then trying to fetch the newly created data, it still fails anyway.

Anyone with knowledge of Django's .save() method and/or some concurrency knowledge help me out here? Much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**
The issue was that I was wrapping all of functionA in an atomic block (forgot to write that part of functionA originally), which meant that the transactions don't commit until after functionA returns!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the correct value for "blogTitle" in functionB? 
Also, for the exception, you should use `except Blog.DoesNotExist`.